# Как правильно сказать

Tags: стилистика

"Принимая этот препарат, человеку становится легче" — правильно ли так говорить?

Comment: А Вы о знаках препинания слышали что-нибудь? Или о том, что предложения полагается начинать с большой буквы и брать в кавычки? Нет?

Answer (score 8):

Так неправильно. Нет субъекта добавочного действия. Правильно: принимая этот препарат, человек чувствует облегчение.

Answer (score 0):

Так как предложение безличное, не понятно, кто принимает препарат.

Answer (score 0):

Э-мм... Всё-таки лучше "Приняв этот препарат, человек (по)чувствует облегчение".
Иначе фраза описывает эффект плацебо: ещё только принимает, и тут же чувствует... :) 
Понятно, что имеется в виду регулярное или продолжительное действие, но неодновременность стоит, мне кажется, подчеркнуть.